# Not In use with group by in oracle Sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT A.SALE_ID,COUNT(A.SALE_ID) AS TOTAL_PENDING,C.ALLOTTE,C.FORM_NO,E.CUS_NAME
    FROM B_UNIT_BOOKING_DETAIL A
    JOIN COD_BOOKING_MASTER C ON A.SALE_ID=C.SALE_ID 
    JOIN COD_FORM_REG D ON C.FORM_NO=D.FORM_NO 
    JOIN COD_CUSTOMER_MASTER E ON E.CUS_ID=C.ALLOTTE
    WHERE A.DUE_DATE < '20-AUG-21' AND A.RECEIVED='N' AND 
    (SELECT COUNT(B.SALE_ID) FROM B_UNIT_BOOKING_DETAIL B 
    WHERE B.DUE_DATE < '20-AUG-21' AND B.RECEIVED='N' 
    AND B.SALE_ID=A.SALE_ID GROUP BY B.SALE_ID  ) > '2' 
    AND E.PROJECT_ID='4'
    AND E.COMPANY_ID='2' AND C.FORM_NO NOT IN (SELECT REG_NO FROM COD_RECOVERY_RECORD) AND ROWNUM <= 50 
    GROUP BY A.SALE_ID ,C.ALLOTTE,C.FORM_NO,D.CUS_ID,E.CUS_NAME
```

[image: error given in this picture]

This query shows the error invalid number but I check all the field every datatype is correct by still its showing error can anyone please tell me how I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.SALE_ID,COUNT(A.SALE_ID) AS TOTAL_PENDING,C.ALLOTTE,C.FORM_NO,E.CUS_NAME
    FROM B_UNIT_BOOKING_DETAIL A
    JOIN COD_BOOKING_MASTER C ON A.SALE_ID=C.SALE_ID 
    JOIN COD_FORM_REG D ON C.FORM_NO=D.FORM_NO 
    JOIN COD_CUSTOMER_MASTER E ON E.CUS_ID=C.ALLOTTE
    WHERE A.DUE_DATE < '20-AUG-21' AND A.RECEIVED='N' AND 
    (SELECT COUNT(B.SALE_ID) FROM B_UNIT_BOOKING_DETAIL B 
    WHERE B.DUE_DATE < '20-AUG-21' AND B.RECEIVED='N' 
    AND B.SALE_ID=A.SALE_ID GROUP BY B.SALE_ID  ) > '2' 
    AND E.PROJECT_ID='4'
    AND E.COMPANY_ID='2' AND D.FORM_NO NOT IN (SELECT REG_NO FROM COD_RECOVERY_RECORD) AND ROWNUM <= 50 
    GROUP BY A.SALE_ID ,C.ALLOTTE,C.FORM_NO,D.CUS_ID,E.CUS_NAME
```

I just change ALLASES OF FORM_NO TO GET BTHE RESULT.